# Work with foreach in Laravel: delete same values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I found way to delete duplicate values in the result but it doesn't work correctly. How to fix it?

I have next code:

```
    public function getListPositionByApplication($app_id){
    // $app_id = \Request::input('app_id');
    $list = SparePartApplicationPositionProvider::where('app_id',$app_id)->with(['provider','application_position'])->orderBy('apos_id')
            ->get();
            $aa=0;
            foreach ($list as $value) {
                if($value->apos_id==$aa){
                    $value->application_position->name_detail='----';
                }
                $aa = $value->apos_id;
                 Log::info($value->apos_id);
            }

    return $list;
}
```

Log::info give next information: 26,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,27,28
but $value->application_position->name_detail have '----' in all cases with the exception of last value

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarkSkayff $aa = $value->apos_id; - we save current value, if next value is same - if($value->apos_id==$aa) we change field releted model.

Comment: why don't you use eloquent `groupBy` have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

@Hussein is right, group by the common column and don't do a foreach. Let the Eloquent DB do the heavy lifting. Notice the callback where you include your second table.

```
    $list = SparePartApplicationPositionProvider::where('app_id',$app_id)
->with(['provider','application_position' => function ($query){
    $query->groupBy('name_detail');
    }])
->orderBy('apos_id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try collection unique() method.

> https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-unique